# Print a webpage to a PDF file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, tableau-api

I have a tableau URL with a grid report in it. I need to print the page to pdf(A3) using python. Is there a way to achieve it. I tried using pdfkit and requests.get method but which is not giving proper output.

```
import requests
url = 'http://tabiisweb.sample.com/'
myfile = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True,stream = True)
open('c:/tabfile.pdf', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

Comment: `pdfkit.from_url`

Comment: I am getting and empty pdf while using this function. This is working for normal websites but not working for the one which I needed.

Comment: Than there is something special with that webpage you are exporting. You tagged tableau, so perhaps you need to do something particular for that software to get pdf's. (So, not using pdfkit.)